# Optimizing Azure VM A0

Tags: azure

Average CPU Percentage 15%

Average Disk read
110.69 KB/s

Average Disk write
42.88 KB/s

Internal log show sporadic performance, sometimes reading 12 files faster than reading 2 files

Server being put on South East Asia, tested from West Europe

Serving simple wordpress takes 3 seconds
Serving complex wordpress takes 15 seconds
Serving asp.net core takes 2-5 seconds

I'm aware network bandwidth limited to 5 Mbps

The question is, is this expected performance? Is there anything I can do more to optimize this VM?

If I move it to T2 Micro in AWS, will it be much better?

Changing the size of VM is not solution.

Comment: Down voter can only suggest to go size A1

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use GRS within azure storage, use LRS
- Always disconnect from RDP, never let anything open
- Use free CDN
- Using closer server to host things may help latency, but my problem is that my audience are in different continent
- Migrate to ARM, don't use classic deployment
- <s>Use disk striping</s> **This increase the cost significantly**
- Avoid response redirect
- etc

I successfully optimizing it to serve page within 1 second (consistently), what you have to keep in mind is memory is precious resource, while disk is cheap but slow